# AWS Subnet error: "The CIDR conflicts with another subnet"

Tags: amazon-web-services, subnet

Another AWS subnet error

Resource handler returned message:

> The CIDR '192.168.128.0/18' conflicts with another subnet (Service: Ec2, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 4247b91e-a7aa-4d34-8f45-b832fc293682, Extended Request ID: null)" (RequestToken: 86aa6d5e-6f29-1cdf-c6c8-868bd964bdd6, HandlerErrorCode: AlreadyExists)

My configuration:

- VPC: 192.168.0.0/16
- PublicSubnet01:  192.168.0.0/18
- PrivateSubnet01: 192.168.64.0/18
- PublicSubnet02:  192.168.128.0/18
- PrivateSubnet02: 192.168.192.0/18

Any hint?

Comment: Are you sure that there aren't any other existing subnets? What were you doing when this error appeared? Were you using the VPC management console, or was it via an API call or perhaps CloudFormation? More information, please.